# Boost headers not found after brew installation macos

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++, homebrew

```
fileman.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
```

I understand the boost libraries should be located in usr/local/lib, but my lib directory only has "bin" and "share" folders in it. When I use `findmd name- boost`, this is returned

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/tests/data/boost.npz
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XGBoostFramework.framework
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XGBoostFramework.framework
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XGBoostFramework.framework/Versions/A/XGBoostFramework.tbd
```

I don't think any of these are the proper files to compile with g++ but I'm not sure what to look for :(

Should I have an usr/local/lib folder?
Am I doing something wrong?

I am very new to installations from terminal, so I'm sorry if I'm just misunderstanding something. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you said you there're only two folder, `bin` and `share`, in `usr/local/` made me think you might have a M1 Mac.

For Intel Macs, Homebrew is installed in `usr/local` by default, which should at least add a folder named `Homebrew` in `usr/local`. Since you didn't find anything there, you either had a M1 Mac which defaults to a different location, or you have manually installed it in a different location.

In case you had a M1 Mac, Homebrew is installed in `opt/homebrew` by default. And you should be able to find a `include` folder in there.